# Eclipse Save Action - Package-private comment

Tags: java, eclipse, scope

If we define a Java class such as:
class MyClass

Our team would like developers to always specify the scope using a comment, e.g.,
/* package */class MyClass

The same would be nice for variables. It doesn't appear that standard Eclipse Save Actions provides the ability to automatically add the comment on Save. Is there an existing plugin that provides this functionality?

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same what the modifier already does? That sounds like a horrible idea, pretty much the more sophisticated equivalent of `i++; // increment i`

Comment: I just like for our team to be consistent with pre-existing codebase and the Save Actions are a very nice way to accomplish that for many things. However, when you put it that way, I suppose the 'package' comment is redundant. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to mark the class and variables with a `/* package */` when the scope modifier is missing.

I suspect what you want is to determine when a developer has accidentally left off the scope modifier.  The developer should type the `/* package */` manually when he or she wants the scope to be package, rather than have the Eclipse IDE automatically insert the comment(s).

Your Eclipse plug-in would flag missing `/* package */` comments, so that the developer can explicitly specify the scope.  You would have to develop this Eclipse plug-in.

Comment: Yes, what you described would also be great. Initially I was thinking of it as a Save Action since the developer may notice that Eclipse auto-added the 'package' comment and would then would have increased chance of thinking about what the proper scope should be. But what you describe would be even better, say if it were a part of Checkstyle-like plugin. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your own plug-in. Look in your Eclipse help for creating a clean-up.